# Bases of the annihilator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the subspace of  $\mathbb{R}^5$which is spanned by the vectors $\alpha_{1}$ = $\epsilon_1$ + $2\epsilon_2$ +$\epsilon_3$, $\alpha_2$ = $\epsilon_2$ + $3\epsilon_3$ + $3\epsilon_4$ + $\epsilon_5$, $\alpha_3$ = $\epsilon_1$ + $4\epsilon_2$ + $6\epsilon_3$ + $4\epsilon_4$ + $\epsilon_5$. Find a basis for $W^o$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Notice that
$$\dim W^°=\dim\Bbb R^5-\dim W=2$$
Let 
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^5 a_k\epsilon_k\in W^°$$
then we have
$$\langle x,\alpha_i\rangle=0,\quad i=1,2,3$$
so solve this system of equations and find two solutions *(which give two independent vectors)*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Do you understand that the dimension of $W^°$ is $2$?

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve the problem thanks for the hint.

Comment: You're welcome and I hope that it was helpful!